# Anonymous functions with varargin

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, handle, variadic-functions

I have a function that takes 3 mandatory inputs and 1 optional:

```
 f(A, B, C, X)
```

I want to use an anonymous function in this way

```
h = @(X)f(A,B,C,X)
```

where `A, B, C` have already been defined, so that I can just call `h(1)` and the code runs `f(A,B,C,1)`, as well as `h()` to run `f(A,B,C)`.
The only way I am able to do it (correct me if I am wrong) is using `varargin`. I define

```
f(A,B,C,varargin)
```

and use

```
h = @(varargin)f(A,B,C,varargin)
```

The problem is that when I call directly `f(A,B,C,1)`, then inside the function I have `varargin = {1}`. If I call `h(1)`, then I have `varargin = {{1}}`. How can I avoid that? Is there a better way to implement what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to (or, rather, it may be best to) expand `varargin` into a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) with your current implementation:

```
h = @(varargin)f(A,B,C,varargin{:})
```

The question of if there is a better way is dependent on the specifics of the problem.

Comment: I don't see any downsides, using `varargin{:}` is how it should be done.

Comment: @Daniel Neither do I, but I didn't like the forcefulness of "need" at the time.